# Search through nested array of objects for string and set IsCheckedIn flag = true;

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the array of objects below. If the user enters the string '00006844763487934739' how can I search through this nested Items array and search for '00006844763487934739' and set isChecked in = true where it matches

[image]

Comment: Post the code that you attempted as well.

Comment: Please don't post the images of the code. Instead post the real javascript code/data which we can directly use for solution without need to modify it. And also tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` if there are no circular references in your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to directly modify the array:

```
function checkIn(data, LP) {
  data.forEach((entry) => {
    const matchingItem = entry.Items.find(i => i.LP === LP);
    if (matchingItem) {
      matchingItem.IsCheckedIn = true;
    }
  });

  return data;
}
```

And you would use it like (assuming `data` is your array):

```
checkIn(data, '00006844763487934739');
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested `filter` would do the job.

```js
let data = [
 { CustomerName: "Thomas", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934739", IsCheckedIn: false }] },
 { CustomerName: "Joey", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934738", IsCheckedIn: false }] },
 { CustomerName: "Robert", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934739", IsCheckedIn: true }] }
];

let matches = data.filter(customer => customer.Items.filter(item => item.LP === "00006844763487934739" && item.IsCheckedIn).length > 0);

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` creates a new array, so try to use `foreach`:

```
let searchString = '00006844763487934739';
let data = [
    { CustomerName: "Thomas", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934739", IsCheckedIn: false }] },
    { CustomerName: "Joey", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934738", IsCheckedIn: false }] },
    { CustomerName: "Robert", Items: [{ LP: "00006844763487934739", IsCheckedIn: true }] }
  ];

data.forEach((e, i) => {
    e.Items.forEach(a => {
        if(a.LP ==searchString)
            a.IsCheckedIn = true;
    })
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you wanted to modify the existing array so you can do it like so:

```js
var data = [
  {
    Items: [
      { LP: '1', IsCheckedIn: false},
      { LP: '00006844763487934739', IsCheckedIn: false}
    ]
  },
  {
    Items: [
      { LP: '3', IsCheckedIn: false},
      { LP: '00006844763487934739', IsCheckedIn: false}
    ]
  },
  {
    Items: [
      { LP: '4', IsCheckedIn: false},
      { LP: '5', IsCheckedIn: false}
    ]
  }
];

var lookupId = '00006844763487934739';

data.flatMap(dataItem => dataItem.Items).forEach(item => item.IsCheckedIn = item.LP === lookupId);

console.log(data);
```